# Exclude inner level dependencies

Tags: maven

I need to exclude dependency org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j from my project.
Dependency tree is look like follows.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ DataImportLoader ---
[INFO] com.kipstor:DataImportLoader:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.11:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.11:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.11:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.opengis.cite.xerces:xercesImpl-xsd11:jar:2.12-beta-r1667115:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.opengis.cite.eclipse.webtools.sse:org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor:jar:1.1.5-738bb7b85d:compile
[INFO] |     \- edu.princeton.cup:java-cup:jar:10k:compile
[INFO] +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc-driver:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile
```

I tried to remove it using following configuration in POM. But it seems not working. Can anybody point out the correct way of doing this?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
             <artifactId>org.slf4j</artifactId>
             <groupId>log4j-over-slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Check to ensure that you don't have the `spring-boot-starter-web` declared multiple times. Then check the `dependency:tree` again to see if another dependency is pulling it in.

Comment: @Steve C . I have update the full dependency tree. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typographical error in your dependency declaration. It should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

You have the `artifactId` and `groupId` element content back to front in the exclusion.